# C Programming- How to delete a line containing a specific word from file?

Tags: c, file-handling

I have created a stock inventory program for a jewelry store.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to search for a specific word in a file containing the items (in a table form) and delete the entire line which the word was on.

For example, I can delete earring from the list but not the quantity as well which would be a few spaces away on the same line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;

    //consider 40 character string to store filename
    char filename[40];
    char c;
    int del_line, temp = 1;

    //asks user for file name
    printf("Enter file name: ");

    //receives file name from user and stores in 'filename'
    scanf("%s", filename);

    //open file in read mode
    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    c = getc(fp1);

    //until the last character of file is obtained
    while (c != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);
        //print current character and read next character
        c = getc(fp1);
    }
    //rewind
    rewind(fp1);
    printf(" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:");
    //accept number from user.
    scanf("%d", &del_line);

    //open new file in write mode
    fp2 = fopen("copy.c", "w");
    c = getc(fp1);
    while (c != EOF) {
        c = getc(fp1);
        if (c == '\n')
            temp++;
        //except the line to be deleted
        if (temp != del_line) {
            //copy all lines in file copy.c
            putc(c, fp2);
        }
    }

    //close both the files.
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    //remove original file
    remove(filename);

    //rename the file copy.c to original name
    rename("copy.c", filename);
    printf("\n The contents of file after being modified are as  follows:\n");

    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    c = getc(fp1);

    while (c != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = getc(fp1);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempts, and why is it having problems.

Comment: I'd probably use `fgets()` to read whole lines, and then `strstr()` to find the search string. If `strstr()` returns 0, write the line out. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: Aside: `c = getc(fp1);  while (c != EOF) { c = getc(fp1); ...` - aren't you overwriting the first character here?

Comment: "*I have created a stock inventory program for a jewelry store*" have you considered using a database? Even something like [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) would be vastly superior to a text file.

Comment: I'd also point out that there's nothing your program is doing that couldn't be done easier, by the user, with a text editor.  Less work, less bugs, more flexibility. If you must write a program, consider doing it in a language more conducive to manipulating text and files like Python or Perl or Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several issues:

- You read the filename with an unprotected call to `scanf`, if the name typed by the user exceeds 39 characters, you invoke undefined behavior.  Make the buffer larger as filenames tend to be long nowadays and protect the format this way:

  ```
  char filename[256];

  if (scanf("%255s", filename) != 1) {
      /* end of file reached, deal with this error */
      ...
  }
  ```
- Your method for reading a file byte by byte is incorrect: `c` should be defined as an `int` otherwise you cannot reliably detect `EOF`. The standard idiom for this is:

  ```
  int c;

  //until the last character of file is obtained
  while ((c = getc(fp1)) != EOF) {
      //print current character and read next character
      putchar(c);
  }
  ```
- In the copy phase, you drop the first character of the file.
- You ignore errors.  Not only do you invoke undefined behavior, you may actually erase the file after failing to copy its contents.
- You ask for a line number from the user, but you do not show the line numbers in the echo phase.  Doing so would help.

Here is a improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;

    //consider 255 character string to store filename
    char filename[256];
    int c, last, del_line, lineno;

    //asks user for file name
    printf("Enter file name: ");

    //receives file name from user and stores in 'filename'
    if (scanf("%255s", filename) != 1) {
        perror("missing filename");
        return 1;
    }

    //open file in read mode
    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open file");
        return 1;
    }

    //until the last character of file is obtained
    last = '\n';
    lineno = 0;
    while ((c = getc(fp1)) != EOF) {
        if (last == '\n') {
            printf("%4d: ", ++lineno);
        }
        //print current character and read next character
        putchar(c);
        last = c;
    }

    rewind(fp1);
    printf("\nEnter line number of the line to be deleted: ");
    //accept number from user.
    if (scanf("%d", &del_line) != 1) {
        perror("missing line number");
        return 1;
    }
    if (del_line < 1 || del_line > lineno) {
        printf("no such line: %d\n", del_line);
        return 1;
    }

    //open new file in write mode
    fp2 = fopen("copy.c", "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open copy.c");
        return 1;
    }

    lineno = 1;
    while ((c = getc(fp1)) != EOF) {
        //except the line to be deleted
        if (lineno != del_line) {
            //copy all lines in file copy.c
            putc(c, fp2);
        }
        if (c == '\n')
            lineno++;
    }

    //close both files.
    fclose(fp1);
    if (fclose(fp2)) {
        perror("write error to copy.c");
        return 1;
    }

    // remove original file (unsafe)
    // uncomment this if your system does not allow rename
    // to overwrite existing files
    // if (remove(filename)) {
    //     perror("cannot remove source file");
    //     return 1;
    // }

    //rename the file copy.c to original name
    if (rename("copy.c", filename)) {
        perror("cannot rename file");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nThe contents of file after being modified are as  follows:\n");

    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        perror("cannot re-open modified file");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = getc(fp1)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quite complete! +1  Pedantic idea: rather than `[delete 1] [rename 2 to 1]`, instead `[rename 2 to 3] [rename 2 1] [delete 3]`.  This keeps the original around until after a new one is made and renamed.  Better chance to restore original if ` [rename 2 1]` fails.

Comment: @chux: that's a good point, especially since it is easy for `rename` to fail: just running the program from the home directory and editing a file on a USB key will do that.  On a unix system, the safer way is to call `rename` without a previous call to `remove`.  `rename` will remove the file and rename the new file in one atomic operation, if the rights are OK.  I don't know if Windows supports this, but would not be surprised if they wouldn't.

Comment: @chux: I updated the answer for unix users, and added line numbering.